# load column data into checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to load r1,r2,r3 column to a checkboxlist, but the output is not my expected result

**data inside my db**

Question   r1  r2  r3

who am i? A B C

**output(item that inside my checkboxlist)**

A

**Expected output**

A

B

C

i was tried to add r1,r2,r3 into DataTextField but asp.net not allow me to do so=(

```
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="r1" DataValueField="r1">

    </asp:CheckBoxList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 

        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [r1], [r2], [r3] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question)">

        <SelectParameters>

            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="who am i?" Name="Question" Type="String" />

        </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the select command:

```
SELECT [r1] AS [Option] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question)
UNION
SELECT [r2] AS [Option] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question)
UNION
SELECT [31] AS [Option] FROM [ExerciseTable] WHERE ([Question] = @Question)
```

Comment: it no work and the output is 
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'r1'.

Comment: oops,i change it to option and try,it return me the output
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.